# Prerender Link using Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I need to add a Pre render link to my asp.net page. I am doing it like this.

```
<link rel="prerender" href="Test.aspx?v=1.1">
```

the querystring 'v' is dynamic, and can change based on some value. So how can i either add a variable in the markup

or

is there a way by which i can add this Pre render link in Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a JavaScript solution:

```
var version = '1.1';
var link = document.createElement('link'); //Create link-Element
link.setAttribute('rel', 'prerender'); //Set rel-Attribute
link.setAttribute('href', 'Test.aspx?v=' + version); //Set href-Attribute
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link); //Append link-Element to HEAD
```

Answer (score 0):

Add public variable to your code file (Test.aspx.cs)

```
public double myValue = 1.1;
```

Then you can change it where ever you want in this file

Use next format for including value to your markup

```
<link rel="prerender" href="Test.aspx?v=<%= myValue %>">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use in you code behind as follows

```
 public double myValue = 1.1;
 var myHtmlLink = new HtmlLink { Href = "Test.aspx?v="+myValue };
 myHtmlLink.Attributes.Add("rel", "stylesheet");
 myHtmlLink.Attributes.Add("type", "text/css");
 Page.Header.Controls.AddAt(0, myHtmlLink);
```